# open id or single sign on like stackoverflow

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I m very impressed with the idea of stackoverflow, the way they provide the options to login to the users is very easy for any user. And if I have to do the same thing in my website then how its going to be. what will be the coding structure and coding snippets for the same in php , mysql and javascript (ajax).

https://stackoverflow.com/users/login

Comment: Start here: http://openid.net/add-openid/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661/how-do-i-use-more-than-one-openid#112662

Comment: Thanks Jason for info. I want to confirm that the website openid.net is for creating my openid for my own website like the way google provide provide it. Correct ??.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple OpenID [class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3290-PHP-Authenticate-users-with-OpenID-single-sign-on.html), that provides some functionality. First, you need to register an OpenID URL, then, simply type your OpenID in form in `openid-example.php` and it will redirect you to your OpenID provider, just as you do it on StackOverflow. Then, after your confirmation, it will redirect you back with some personal information, which you can use on your site.

Comment: Thanks Buddy, I'll try this class. And will get back if I face any kind of hurdles.